# .NET How to define an Async task Callback

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-core, task

I am updating my code from a BackgroundWorker to Tasks and am running into an issue.  I would like to mimic the functionality that BackgroundWorker has where, when the `DoWork()` thread completes, the BackgroundWorker calls the `DoWorkCompleted()` function.  Here's what I have so far:

```
Private Sub btn_Start_Click(sender, e) Handles btn_Start.Click
  btn_Stop.IsEnabled = True
  btn_Start.IsEnabled = False
  _cts = New CancellationTokenSource()
  Dim theWork As Task = Worker.Start(_cts.Token)
  theWork.ContinueWith(AddressOf OnWorkCompleted)
End Sub

Private Sub OnWorkCompleted()
  btn_Stop.IsEnabled = False
  btn_Start.IsEnabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub btn_Stop_Click(sender, e) Handles btn_Stop.Click
  _cts.Cancel()
End Sub
```

Then in another file, Worker.vb, I have the following:

```
Private Shared _cts As CancellationToken

Public Shared Function Start(token As CancellationToken) As Task
  Try
    _cts = token
    Return Task.Run(AddressOf Process, token)
  Catch ex As TaskCanceledException
    MessageBox.Show("Task cancelled")
    Return Task.CompletedTask
  End Try
End Function

Private Shared Async Sub Process()
  Try
    Log.Information("0")
    Await Task.Delay(1000, _cts)
    Log.Information("1")
    Await Task.Delay(1000, _cts)
    Log.Information("2")
    Await Task.Delay(1000, _cts)
    Log.Information("3")
    Await Task.Delay(1000, _cts)
    Log.Information("4")
    Await Task.Delay(1000, _cts)
  Catch ex As OperationCanceledException
    MessageBox.Show("cancelled operation")
  End Try
End Sub
```

Pretty much, what I want to happen with this code is to mimic what will happen with the full code when I migrate it over:  after a user clicks start, a long operation runs on a separate thread and the UI is still responsive.  If at any point the user clicks Stop, the task will end and the `OnWorkCompleted` function will be called.  What happens, is the OnWorkCompleted() is called immediately and not when Stop is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, you should [avoid `Async Sub`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void):

```vb
Private Shared Async Function Process() As Task
```

Also, use `Await` instead of `ContinueWith`:

```vb
Private Async Sub btn_Start_Click(sender, e) Handles btn_Start.Click
  btn_Stop.IsEnabled = True
  btn_Start.IsEnabled = False
  _cts = New CancellationTokenSource()
  Try
    Await Worker.Start(_cts.Token)
  Finally
    OnWorkCompleted()
  End Try
End Sub
```

You may find my blog post series on [replacing `BackgroundWorker` with `Task.Run`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html) helpful.

Comment: That's not working. It's going right to the `OnWorkCompleted()` function. I have updated my `Process()` method with what I'm doing currently doing in it

Comment: Did you change it to be `Function`?